# My Ionic application Build Successfully but wont launch the application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, deployment

I build an application, while the development process, I deployed the application many times successfully on Android devices, but this time i tried to deploy it, it build it successfully, but there is no output application or Launching the application operation.
here is some of information:

```
deploy the app using:
> ionic cordova build android

the output of this command is:
    ...
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL

    Total time: 1 mins 9.612 secs
    Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Users/Laila Shreteh/notification/notificationsProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
```

there is no any other actions, no application on device.

> Note: i checked if the PC reads the android device, it is the same device is deployed the app many times before.

Comment: Are you generated the signed apk file?

Comment: can please specify more?

Comment: Are you generate the signed APK file for realese

Comment: Do you already tried follow this doc -> https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/ ?

Comment: im following the IONIC documentation deployment section, and im typing this command: ionic cordova build android, and it worked fine with me many times

Answer (score 0):

If you have attached a device, you can launch the App on it with this command:

```
adb install your_filename_with_path.apk
```

Here you have all the information about how that command works:
[Android Debug Bridge (adb)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)

Comment: You need to have the device in developer mode.
Here is the info to [Run Apps on a Hardware Device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html?hl=en-419)